# delete row from table

Tags: android, sqlite

when I want to delete a row from my table, the toast shows me "error" while the line has been deleted

```
Supprimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM Biblio WHERE nom = \""+user.getText().toString()+"\" AND type= \""+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\"",null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Erreur",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you adding the slashes?

Comment: Use Prepared Statements to make those queries secure and readable

Comment: int result x =  db.delete("Biblio", "nom =" + nameuser.getText().toString()+" AND type= "+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), null);

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin , there is no probleme with slashes , the query works , the probleme is in (c.movetofirst)

Comment: @OussemaAroua x take what value, if the query works or if it not working

Comment: it takes the number of deleted rows, if nothing deleted so it takes 0 if there are rows it take >0

Comment: rawQuery returns a cursor but delete returns rows deleted, so the rawQuery statement is, I think, unusual. I would recommend something like the following: 'db.delete ("Biblio", "nom = ? AND type= ?", String[] {user.getText().toString(),spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());' You will get an int back that is the number of rows deleted.

Comment: @OussemaAroua i have an error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abbes4 (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Biblio WHERE nom =abbes4 AND type= CD" while the column abbes 4 is in the table

Comment: @Cheticamp i have an error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abbes4 (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Biblio WHERE nom =abbes4 AND type= CD" while the column abbes 4 is in the table

Comment: the problem is your column doesn't exists verifie your table columns

Comment: @OussemaAroua the name of the column is "nom" I want to delete the line abbes4 that is in column "nom"

Comment: It is odd that it would complain about "abbes4" as a column since the named columns are "nom" and "type". Can you show your code?

Comment: @Cheticamp the name of the column is "nom" I want to delete the line abbes4 that is in column "nom"

Comment: That is what the code I gave you should do. Posting your code would be helpful.

Comment: @Cheticamp int x = db.delete("Biblio", "nom =" + user.getText().toString()+" AND type= "+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), null);

Comment: You need quotes around abbes4 and CD. Otherwise, they are interpreted as column names which is what the error message is saying. The code I gave you would've bound those values as strings, so it would not have been an issue. Add the quotes to your statement or go with the statement I gave you. Either way should work and be OK. I am looking at my statement again, and I notice that there is a parenthesis at the end that should be a brace.

Comment: @Cheticamp thank you it's working :)

Comment: Great! Glad it is. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Cheticamp Please write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawQuery` returns a cursor but `delete` returns rows deleted, so the `rawQuery` statement is, I think, unusual. I would recommend something like the following:

```
db.delete ("Biblio", "nom = ? AND type = ?", new String[]  {user.getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()})
```

You will get an int back that is the number of rows deleted.